# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID Resources.getText when running test as part of shard

Tags: android, sharding, android-instrumentation

During an instrumentation test i request the context the following way

```
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

then somewhere in the test i do

```
device.waitForText(context.getString(R.string.someString))
```

This works well when I run the test as a single test and when I run the test as part of a test suite.

However, I want to expedite the testing procedures with test [sharding](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/test_infra/tradefed/architecture/advanced/sharding)

And when i invoke the tests as shards, i get an exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f1300e5at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:367)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Write a Sharded IRemoteTest Test Runner](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/test_infra/tradefed/testing/through-tf/sharded-runner) reads:

> Shards need to be independent!
>
> Two shards created by your implementation of split in your runner
>
> **should not have dependencies on each other or share resources**.

Also see [`InstalledInstrumentationsTest.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/tradefederation/+/refs/heads/master/test_framework/com/android/tradefed/testtype/InstalledInstrumentationsTest.java).

Comment: actually i did that. All my tests are independent of each other. My actual problem was that it was not installing the androidTestApk and was working against some strange ghost that was installed on it from sometime before